In LWM2M, Wakaama client -Fota fail and device crash
while I triggered Fota from server i got in response of /5/0/1,4.06- Not acceptable and after that i got in /5/0/5- value 4 which is error of "Loss Connectectivty" and after that device crash, got blue screen error

there are too few details to help you: version, what the server is, what the trigger is, which package download you use, etc. ideally a dump of the LWM2M traffic would be useful

Version is 1.0
cutom server(not much idea)

when fota triger from the Server, and device got notify via /5/0 after that above sceneria happened

/I : [object_readData:213] flag:7, Uri:5/0/5
[ ]     /I : [lwm2m_data_new:142] size: 1
[ ]     /I : |nwy lwm2m|...wm2m_fota_api.c|1178|read NWY_FOTA_STATUS_FILE 0,4
[ ]     /I : [lwm2m_data_encode_int:268] value: 4
[ ]     /I : [object_zreadData:277] result: 2. 5, size: 1
[ ]     /I : [observe_handleRequest:599] Code: 01, server status: STATE_REGISTERED
[ ]     /I : [observe_handleRequest:600] flag:7, Uri:5/0/5
[ ]     /I : [observe_handleRequest:603] count: 1, uriP->flag: 0x7
[ ]     /I : [observe_cancel:687] mid: 0
[ ]     /I : [observe_cancel:728] targetP->parameters =0x80d69498

[D] KERN/E : !!! PANIC AT 601EBEFB
[ ] IPCD/E : NOTIFY CP ASSERT: cp svn version: 58756
[ ]     /E : !!! BLUE SCREEN pc/0x001006e6 lr/0x001006e7 sp/0x80d55020 cpsr/0x000701db spsr/0x800700bf
